# Detecting if the server still has an ajax request using different browser c# jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm currently developing a website and having trouble finding the right solution.

When I open my site from a different browser and tried to make an AJAX call at the same time, I get an error, because both the browsers are processing the request.

Is there a way to detect if the server is currently executing an AJAX call and wait until it finishes the first request before executing the second one?

here is my code when i tried to make an ajax request at the same time using different browsers

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(hhpPath + "\\Contents\\" + Path.GetFileName(hhpPath).ToString() + ".hhp", false))
            {

                sw.WriteLine("[OPTIONS]");
                sw.WriteLine("Compatibility=1.1 or later");
                sw.WriteLine("Compiled file=" + hhpPath + "\\Unpublished\\"+ Name +".chm");  //the file to be converted
                sw.WriteLine("Contents file=" + (hhpPath + "\\Contents\\" + Path.GetFileName(hhpPath).ToString()) + ".hhc"); //TOC file
                sw.WriteLine("Default topic=" + "Installing the Prototype Terminal.html");
                sw.WriteLine("Display compile progress=no");
                sw.WriteLine("Index file=" + (hhpPath + "\\Contents\\" + Path.GetFileName(hhpPath).ToString()) + ".hhk"); //index file
                sw.WriteLine("Title=none");
                sw.WriteLine("\r\n[FILES]");
                sw.WriteLine("none");
            }
```

the error says that the file is currently on use.

Comment: Please post code where you face the issue? What is error? Ideally,there is separate thread for each request. So no need to worry about the conflict in the call.

Comment: yes i know that i just need to finish the ajax call before calling the following request because my class is using an .exe or 3rd party program and when they request to run that .exe file it has an error because someone is currently in use of another person so i need to wait until the ajax call is complete.

Comment: Done posting the code i included it in the question above

Comment: You need to do some serverside/database tracking for this .

Comment: could you give me some reference that i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it is an AJAX call via jQuery is irrelevant. You problem is: your website tries to exclusively access a resource (in your case, write to a constant file) on a request.

Since the website is designed to simultaneously serve a lot of clients, you will inevitably run into access issues.

The functionality you're trying to achieve isn't really typical for a website. Could you please describe what problem you are trying to solve, so that we could give you a better advise?

Possible solutions could be a combination of:

- Write to a different file on each request
- (as suggested in another answer) Gracefully handle the file access error: either wait until it's free, or return an error
- Use a database instead of the file system for writing data
- Limit this feature to specific clients
- Remove this feature altogether

Comment: im trying to convert a bundles of HTML file to CHM using HTML HELP WORKSHOP ang im writting the file that is needed to cenvert HTML files to CHM my problem is when to browser convert a CHM file at the same time im having an error because it happened that they are trying to use a file at the same time which is logically not right. im currently trying your advices and see if it works currently finding an answer for this problem

Comment: This became even less clear. I don't even know what question to ask next.

Comment: Thanks for this idea i have come up with a solution

by assigning a random file name for every request so that the writer is not writing same file name to fix the error "Is using by a different user,"

Answer (score 1):

When you make ajax request its not directly possible to detect on client side if file is in use . You can put a try catch around that item and return a -1(file locked) status 1(success) or 0(some other error).

Or try following function to check before your code to see if file is in use and return related status to ajax calls.

```
  protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        Boolean status = false;
        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            status = false ;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
            status = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        //file is not locked
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: The file could become locked after you call `IsFileLocked()`, so the function doesn't serve its intended purpose.

Comment: @Zruty in finally there is   stream.Close(); will unlock file , which will lock file for some microseconds . Only if the other request falls in that very short time it will conflict .

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock the file while writing content in file as like below

```
lock (lockObject) 
{
  var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
  sw.Write('text');
  sw.Flush();
  sw.Close();
}
```

Please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link for thread synchronization.

Comment: This will work but what if write time is longer , it will timeout the ajax request in browser .

Comment: Yes you are right. We can check whether file is locked for writing. If yes then send acknowledge message else process that request. Another way is to tracking file processing in the database.